# Add cron job to save a web link into txt file

Tags: linux, centos, cron

I need to setup a cron job to save a webpage info into a text file in a specified folder at every hour.

here is what I've tried:

```
crontab -e
```

in insert mode I typed:

```
0 * * * * wget http : // webpage url > /foler/test.txt
```

Is this a correct syntax?

Comment: If you types it exactly like it's listed there, this is definitely wrong.

Comment: @Sven I suspect that's the StackOverflow "you can't post a link" rule in play.

Answer (score 4):

The correct form would be

```
0 * * * * wget http://<URL> > /path/to/file
```

e.g.

```
0 * * * * wget http://www.serverfault.com > /tmp/serverfault.html
```

But if the URL gets more complicated, you might need to escape characters and/or put this in quotes.

Comment: I might be old-fashioned or something, but I cringe when I see commands directly in crontab ...I like calling scripts from cron, heh. Well, it works...:P

Answer (score -1):

Thanks alot for your answer. But the syntax didnot work for my particular problem.  Anyway, I used this code to get it all work:

0 * * * * root -O- http : // [ url ] >> /folder/text.txt

I had to difine user name and -O- paramater with two bigger than '>>' sign.

Now everthing works as expected. :)

Comment: Using >> will append to this file, meaning each time the command runs the file will be added to. This will mean, after 24 hours have passed, you will have 24 copies of a web site in one file. If this is as you intended then fair enough. If you would rather seperate them out, try replacing "text.txt" with "$(date '+%HH.%d.%m.%y').txt". This will result in a text file formatted like: "16H.09.12.14.txt". i.e: 0 * * * * root -O- http : // [ url ] >> /folder/$(date '+%HH.%d.%m.%y').txt

Comment: Thanks Alex. You are awesome.  Thats what I wanted to do by using >> . I didnt want to overwrite the output file. Yes I am aware about record the datetime but I wasnt nessasry for the problem. Your answer is very straight forward and easy to understand.  Ty again.

Comment: No worries, just a quick note, if you use my command you can switch from using >> to > (it doesn't make a difference in this use case but it's good practice to use the right commands for the right job), i.e: 0 * * * * root -O- http : // [ url ] > /folder/$(date '+%HH.%d.%m.%y').txt

Comment: Also, you should try to choose the right answer if it's given. Seeing as Sven beat me to the punch, to some extent, you should choose his as the answer. Also upvote all comments that were useful to you.